# WineHQ 6.0 - Ubuntu 20.04 - Add USBSTOR.SYS driver support

Tags: ubuntu-20.04, wine, usb-drive

I have launched this program

```
wine 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Rufus\rufus.exe' 2> rufus.log
```

and I have obtained this log:

```
0034:fixme:font:get_name_record_codepage encoding 20 not handled, platform 1.
0034:fixme:font:get_name_record_codepage encoding 20 not handled, platform 1.
0064:fixme:font:get_name_record_codepage encoding 20 not handled, platform 1.
0064:fixme:font:get_name_record_codepage encoding 20 not handled, platform 1.
006c:fixme:font:get_name_record_codepage encoding 20 not handled, platform 1.
006c:fixme:font:get_name_record_codepage encoding 20 not handled, platform 1.
INTEL-MESA: warning: Performance support disabled, consider sysctl dev.i915.perf_stream_paranoid=0

002c:fixme:font:get_name_record_codepage encoding 20 not handled, platform 1.
002c:fixme:font:get_name_record_codepage encoding 20 not handled, platform 1.
0024:fixme:font:get_name_record_codepage encoding 20 not handled, platform 1.
0024:fixme:font:get_name_record_codepage encoding 20 not handled, platform 1.
00c0:fixme:font:get_name_record_codepage encoding 20 not handled, platform 1.
00c0:fixme:font:get_name_record_codepage encoding 20 not handled, platform 1.
00f8:err:ole:com_get_class_object class {ea502722-a23d-11d1-a7d3-0000f87571e3} not registered
00f8:err:ole:com_get_class_object no class object {ea502722-a23d-11d1-a7d3-0000f87571e3} could be created for context 0x1
0058:fixme:mountmgr:mountmgr_ioctl ioctl 6d003c not supported
0024:fixme:oleacc:AccPropServices_ClearHwndProps (000100D2 4294967292 0 0093EDC0 1)
0024:fixme:oleacc:AccPropServices_SetHwndPropStr (000100D2 4294967292 0 {c3a6921b-4a99-44f1-bca6-61187052c431} L"Save to VHD")
0024:fixme:oleacc:AccPropServices_ClearHwndProps (000200D4 4294967292 0 0093EDC0 1)
0024:fixme:oleacc:AccPropServices_SetHwndPropStr (000200D4 4294967292 0 {c3a6921b-4a99-44f1-bca6-61187052c431} L"Compute image checksums")
0024:fixme:oleacc:AccPropServices_ClearHwndProps (000100B4 4294967292 0 0093EE50 1)
0024:fixme:oleacc:AccPropServices_SetHwndPropStr (000100B4 4294967292 0 {c3a6921b-4a99-44f1-bca6-61187052c431} L"Number of passes")
0024:fixme:oleacc:AccPropServices_ClearHwndProps (00010096 4294967292 0 0093EE50 1)
0024:fixme:oleacc:AccPropServices_SetHwndPropStr (00010096 4294967292 0 {c3a6921b-4a99-44f1-bca6-61187052c431} L"Disk ID")
0024:fixme:explorerframe:taskbar_list_SetProgressState iface 01737C10, hwnd 00010054, flags 2 stub!
0024:fixme:tooltips:TOOLTIPS_NotifyFormat hwnd=00030044 wParam=30044 lParam=3
0024:fixme:oleacc:AccPropServices_ClearHwndProps (000300D6 4294967292 0 0093ED40 1)
0024:fixme:oleacc:AccPropServices_SetHwndPropStr (000300D6 4294967292 0 {c3a6921b-4a99-44f1-bca6-61187052c431} L"advanced drive properties")
0024:fixme:oleacc:AccPropServices_ClearHwndProps (000100D8 4294967292 0 0093ED40 1)
0024:fixme:oleacc:AccPropServices_SetHwndPropStr (000100D8 4294967292 0 {c3a6921b-4a99-44f1-bca6-61187052c431} L"advanced format options")
0024:fixme:oleacc:AccPropServices_ClearHwndProps (000100DA 4294967292 0 0093ED40 1)
0024:fixme:oleacc:AccPropServices_SetHwndPropStr (000100DA 4294967292 0 {c3a6921b-4a99-44f1-bca6-61187052c431} L"Multiple buttons")
0024:fixme:tooltips:TOOLTIPS_NotifyFormat hwnd=000100E0 wParam=100e0 lParam=3
0024:fixme:tooltips:TOOLTIPS_NotifyFormat hwnd=000100E2 wParam=100e2 lParam=3
0024:fixme:tooltips:TOOLTIPS_NotifyFormat hwnd=000100E4 wParam=100e4 lParam=3
0024:fixme:tooltips:TOOLTIPS_NotifyFormat hwnd=000100E6 wParam=100e6 lParam=3
0024:fixme:tooltips:TOOLTIPS_NotifyFormat hwnd=000100E8 wParam=100e8 lParam=3
0024:fixme:tooltips:TOOLTIPS_NotifyFormat hwnd=000100EA wParam=100ea lParam=3
0024:fixme:tooltips:TOOLTIPS_NotifyFormat hwnd=000100EC wParam=100ec lParam=3
0024:fixme:tooltips:TOOLTIPS_NotifyFormat hwnd=000100EE wParam=100ee lParam=3
0024:fixme:tooltips:TOOLTIPS_NotifyFormat hwnd=000100F0 wParam=100f0 lParam=3
0024:fixme:tooltips:TOOLTIPS_NotifyFormat hwnd=000100F2 wParam=100f2 lParam=3
0024:fixme:tooltips:TOOLTIPS_NotifyFormat hwnd=000100F4 wParam=100f4 lParam=3
0024:fixme:tooltips:TOOLTIPS_NotifyFormat hwnd=000100F6 wParam=100f6 lParam=3
0024:fixme:tooltips:TOOLTIPS_NotifyFormat hwnd=000100F8 wParam=100f8 lParam=3
0024:fixme:tooltips:TOOLTIPS_NotifyFormat hwnd=000100FA wParam=100fa lParam=3
0024:fixme:tooltips:TOOLTIPS_NotifyFormat hwnd=000100FC wParam=100fc lParam=3
0024:fixme:tooltips:TOOLTIPS_NotifyFormat hwnd=000100FE wParam=100fe lParam=3
0024:fixme:tooltips:TOOLTIPS_NotifyFormat hwnd=00010100 wParam=10100 lParam=3
0024:fixme:tooltips:TOOLTIPS_NotifyFormat hwnd=00010102 wParam=10102 lParam=3
0024:fixme:tooltips:TOOLTIPS_NotifyFormat hwnd=00010104 wParam=10104 lParam=3
0024:fixme:tooltips:TOOLTIPS_NotifyFormat hwnd=00010106 wParam=10106 lParam=3
0024:fixme:tooltips:TOOLTIPS_NotifyFormat hwnd=00010108 wParam=10108 lParam=3
0024:fixme:tooltips:TOOLTIPS_NotifyFormat hwnd=0001010A wParam=1010a lParam=3
0024:fixme:setupapi:CM_Get_Device_ID_List_SizeA 0093EA30 "USBSTOR" 0x00000102: stub
0024:fixme:setupapi:CM_Get_Device_ID_List_SizeA 0093EA34 "RTSUER" 0x00000102: stub
0024:fixme:setupapi:CM_Get_Device_ID_List_SizeA 0093EA38 "CMIUCR" 0x00000102: stub
0024:fixme:setupapi:CM_Get_Device_ID_List_SizeA 0093EA3C "EUCR" 0x00000102: stub
0024:fixme:setupapi:CM_Get_Device_ID_List_SizeA 0093EA40 "UASPSTOR" 0x00000102: stub
0024:fixme:setupapi:CM_Get_Device_ID_List_SizeA 0093EA44 "VUSBSTOR" 0x00000102: stub
0024:fixme:setupapi:CM_Get_Device_ID_List_SizeA 0093EA48 "ETRONSTOR" 0x00000102: stub
0024:fixme:setupapi:CM_Get_Device_ID_List_SizeA 0093EA4C "ASUSSTPT" 0x00000102: stub
0024:fixme:msg:ChangeWindowMessageFilterEx 00010054 233 1 00000000
0024:fixme:msg:ChangeWindowMessageFilterEx 00010054 4a 1 00000000
0024:fixme:msg:ChangeWindowMessageFilterEx 00010054 49 1 00000000
0024:fixme:font:ExtTextOutW flags ETO_NUMERICSLOCAL | ETO_NUMERICSLATIN unimplemented
00fc:fixme:wininet:InternetSetOptionW INTERNET_OPTION_SEND/RECEIVE_TIMEOUT/DATA_SEND_TIMEOUT 3500
00fc:fixme:wininet:InternetSetOptionW INTERNET_OPTION_SEND/RECEIVE_TIMEOUT/DATA_SEND_TIMEOUT 3500
00fc:fixme:wininet:InternetSetOptionW Option 148 STUB
00fc:fixme:wininet:InternetSetOptionW INTERNET_OPTION_SEND/RECEIVE_TIMEOUT/DATA_SEND_TIMEOUT 3500
00fc:fixme:wininet:InternetSetOptionW INTERNET_OPTION_SEND/RECEIVE_TIMEOUT/DATA_SEND_TIMEOUT 3500
00fc:fixme:wininet:InternetSetOptionW Option 148 STUB
```

On Windows the usb are seen correctly by Rufus and going into the driver information I saw that the usb made use of the USBSTOR.SYS and usbstor.inf driver, not present on WineHQ (It goes without saying that the symlink to the drive was done correctly by Wine, so none of the guides already seen on the internet are useful to me.):

```
0024:fixme:setupapi:CM_Get_Device_ID_List_SizeA 0093EA30 "USBSTOR" 0x00000102: stub
```

How can I correctly install the USBSTOR driver in WineHQ, implementing the relative service?